# I'm having problems when sending User's Id's on a django model

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I'm tryng to do a post method on projetos on my Vue Front-end but i keep getting the error message of "null value in column "professor_id" of relation "fabrica_projeto" violates not-null constraint" even though the request body is the same when i try to post on django-admin and it works there

I'm kinda new to this whole coding world so sorry if my vocabulary is lacking

On Vue/ my front-end
[image]

On Django-Admin(works)

[image]
[image]

This is the model for Projeto
[image]

```
from django.db import models
from usuario.models import Usuario
from uploader.models import Image


class Projeto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=2500)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, related_name='professor', on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    alunos = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, related_name='alunos') 
    capa = models.ForeignKey(
        Image,
        related_name="+",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

My Vue page is looking like this:
(the professor part of the request is getting directly from the current user id):

```
import api from '../plugins/api'
import {useAuthStore} from '../stores/auth'

class WorkspaceService {
  async getAllWorkspaces() {
    const response = await api.get('/projetos/')
    return response.data
  }
  async saveWorkspace(workspace) {
    const authStore = useAuthStore()
    workspace.professor = authStore.user_id
    let response
    if (workspace.id) {
      response = await api.put(`/projetos/${workspace.id}/`, workspace)
    } else {
      response = await api.post('/projetos/', workspace)
    }
    return response.data
  }
  async deleteWorkspac(workspace) {
    const response = await api.delete(`/projetos/${workspace.id}/`)
    return response.data
  }
}

export default new WorkspaceService()
```

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import WorkspaceService from '../services/workspaces'
import UserService from '../services/users';

const users = ref([])

const workspaces = ref([])
const currentWorkspace = ref({
  nome: '',
  descricao: ''
})

onMounted(async () => {
  const data = await UserService.getAllUsers()
  users.value = data
})

onMounted(async () => {
  const data = await WorkspaceService.getAllWorkspaces()
  workspaces.value = data
})

async function save() {
  await WorkspaceService.saveWorkspace(currentWorkspace.value)
  const data = await WorkspaceService.getAllWorkspaces()
  workspaces.value = data
  currentWorkspace.value = { nome: '', descricao: '' }
}

async function deleteWorkspace(workspace) {
  await WorkspaceService.deleteWorkspace(workspace)
  const data = await WorkspaceService.getAllWorkspaces()
  workspaces.value = data
}

function editWorkspace(workspace) {
  currentWorkspace.value = { ...workspace }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <img class="logo" src="../components/icons/logo-green.svg" />
      <div class="nav-list">
        <RouterLink class="nav-links" to="/post">Novo Post</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink class="nav-links" to="/new-workspace">Novo Workspace</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink class="nav-links" to="/home">Home</RouterLink>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <form class="work-box" @submit.prevent="save" >
        <input v-model="currentWorkspace.nome" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Nome do Workspace" />
        <textarea v-model="currentWorkspace.descricao" class="input area" type="text" placeholder="Descrição do Workspace" />
        <label tabindex="0" class="file-input-area">
          <div class="input-image-box">
            <img class="file-input-image" src="../components/icons/clip.svg" />
          </div>
          <span class="image-text">
            Arraste arquivos aqui para anexar, ou
            <span class="highlight">procure-os</span>
          </span>
          <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" name="file_upload" class="file-input" />
        </label>
        <input type="number" v-model="currentWorkspace.alunos" />
        <button type="submit" class="button">Enviar</button>
      </form>

      <div class="work-box">
        <div class="past-posts">
          <h1>Workspaces</h1>
          <div v-for="workspace in workspaces" :key="workspace.id" class="past-post-box">
            <div class="img-pad">
              <img class="post-img" src="../components/icons/logo-green.svg" />
            </div>
            <div class="post-info">
              <h2>{{ workspace.nome }}</h2>
              <p>{{ workspace.descricao }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="post-btns">
              <button class="edit-btn" @click="editWorkspace(workspace)">
                Editar
              </button>
              <button class="delete-btn" @click="deleteWorkspace(workspace)">
                Deletar
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried using workspace.professor.id, and v-model="currentWorkspace.alunos.id" but it doesn't work and gives me another error message of "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"